# Linearity of expectation of hitting time of random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

This is **Exercise 3.2** from the book *Understanding Markov Chains* that I'm getting stuck at.

Consider a random walk $(S_n)$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with independent increments and probabilities $p$, resp. $q = 1 - p$ of moving up by one step, resp. down by one step. Let
$$
     T_0 = \inf\{n \ge 0: S_n = 0\}
$$
denote the hitting time of state $0$. Explain why for any $k \ge 1$, we have
$$
     \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k] = k\mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1]
$$

I tried to show this by induction but this approach requires to compute $\mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1]$ beforehand, which is not intention of this exercise. So if you guys have any hints/guides, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced !

Comment: Hint: use independence of increments to relate the hitting time of $0$ for the walk started from $k$ to the hitting time of $1$ for the walk started from $k$ and the hitting time of $0$ for the walk started from $1$. Then relate the former of these to the hitting time of $0$ for the walk started from $k-1$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thanks for the hint! If I understand correctly, then $$ \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k] = \mathbb{E}[T_1 \vert S_0 = k] + \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1] $$ where $T_1 = \inf\{n \ge 0: S_n = 1\}$ right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RhysSteele's comment, I'll post this answer for future reference.

Let $T_0 = \inf\{n \ge 0: X_n  = 0\}$ and $T_1 = \inf\{n \ge 0: X_n = 1\}$.
Conditional on $S_0 = k \ge 1$, one must have $T_1 \le T_0$. Now,
$$
    \begin{align*}
          \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k] &= \mathbb{E}[T_1 + (T_0 - T_1) \vert S_0 = k]\\
           &= \mathbb{E}[T_1 \vert S_0 = k] + \mathbb{E}[T_0 - T_1 \vert S_0 = k]
    \end{align*}
$$
By the Markov property, we have $\mathbb{E}[T_1 \vert S_0 = k] = \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k - 1]$. Moreover, notice that
$$
      (T_0 - T_1)\vert \{S_0 = k\} = \inf\{n \ge T_1: X_n = 0\} \vert \{S_0 = k\}
$$
Thus, by the strong Markov property, $\mathbb{E}[T_0 - T_1 \vert S_0 = k] = \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1]$. Therefore,
$$
       \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k] = \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k - 1] + \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1]
$$
Applying this for $k$ times, we have
$$
     \mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = k] = k\mathbb{E}[T_0 \vert S_0 = 1]
$$